# Session Variable working in echo but not working in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, session-variables

I want to pass the value of `login.php` variables `$user_key` & `$user_id` to another file `statusdata.php` for which I have used session. In `statusdata.php` I want to use those session variable value in sql query of `statusdata.php` file.

To achieve this in `login.php` I pass the value of variable `$user_key` & `$user_id` to session variable `$_SESSION["key"]` & `$_SESSION["id"]` respectively then in `statusdata.php` I call session variable and pass their value in variable `$user_key` & `$user_id` of `statusdata.php`

Now the problem is when using the variable  `$user_key` & `$user_id` in SQL query it is not returning proper output but using the same variable in echo it is giving proper value mean session is working fine when I echo the variable but not working in SQL. I have also tried passing the session variable directly but the same thing is happening to work in echo but not in SQL.

**`login.php`**

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

require "conn.php";

$user_key = '8C9333343C6C4222418EDB1D7C9F84D051610526085960A1732C7C3D763FFF64EC7F5220998434C896DDA243AE777D0FB213F36B9B19F7E4A244D5C993B8DFED';
$user_id = '1997';

$mysql_qry = "select * from applications where application_key = '".$user_key."' and application_id like '".$user_id."';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $_SESSION["key"] = ".$user_key.";
    $_SESSION["id"] = ".$user_id.";
    echo "Login Success";
}

else {
    echo "Login Not Success";   
}
?>
```

**`statusdata.php`**

```
<?php

// Start the session
session_start();

require "conn.php";

$user_key = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION["key"])) {
  $user_key = $_SESSION["key"];
}

$user_id = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
  $user_id = $_SESSION["id"];
}


 //creating a query
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT applications.application_id, applications.applicant_name, applications.applicant_aadhaar, applications.applicant_phone, applications.subject, applications.date, applications.description, applications.chairperson_remark, applications.status, officer_accounts.name_of_officer, applications.officer_remark, applications.last_update_on 
FROM applications INNER JOIN officer_accounts ON applications.account_id = officer_accounts.account_id 
WHERE applications.application_id = '".$user_id."' AND applications.application_key = '".$user_key."';");

 //executing the query 
 $stmt->execute();

 //binding results to the query 
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $aadhaar, $phone, $subject, $date, $description, $chairperson, $status, $officername, $officerremark, $lastupdate);

 $applications = array(); 

 //traversing through all the result 
 while($stmt->fetch()){
 $temp = array();
 $temp['applications.application_id'] = $id; 
 $temp['applications.applicant_name'] = $name; 
 $temp['applications.applicant_aadhaar'] = $aadhaar; 
 $temp['applications.applicant_phone'] = $phone; 
 $temp['applications.subject'] = $subject;
 $temp['applications.date'] = $date;
 $temp['applications.description'] = $description;
 $temp['applications.chairperson_remark'] = $chairperson;
 $temp['applications.status'] = $status;
 $temp['officer_accounts.name_of_officer'] = $officername;
 $temp['applications.officer_remark'] = $officerremark;
 $temp['applications.last_update_on'] = $lastupdate;
 array_push($applications, $temp);
 }

 //displaying the result in json format 
 echo json_encode($applications);

 // Echo session variables that were set on previous page
 echo "<br>key is " . $user_key . ".<br>";
 echo "id is " . $user_id . ".";

?>
```

**Output `login.php`**

```
Login Success
```

**Output `statusdata.php`**

```
[]
key is .8C9333343C6C4222418EDB1D7C9F84D051610526085960A1732C7C3D763FFF64EC7F5220998434C896DDA243AE777D0FB213F36B9B19F7E4A244D5C993B8DFED..
id is .1997..
```

**output I want from `statusdata.php` (I am getting it if I use direct value in variable `$user_key` & `$user_id` not session variable from login.php)**

```
[{"applications.application_id":1997,"applications.applicant_name":"Tanishq","applications.applicant_aadhaar":"987654321","applications.applicant_phone":"123456789","applications.subject":"asdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsavasdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsav","applications.date":"2018-07-02 09:11:47","applications.description":"asdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsavasdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsavasdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsavasdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsavasdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsav","applications.chairperson_remark":"asdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsavasdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsav","applications.status":1,"officer_accounts.name_of_officer":"Chayan Bansal","applications.officer_remark":"asdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsavasdnjsnadnksncdnsjnvsav","applications.last_update_on":"2018-07-22 09:14:25"}]
key is 8C9333343C6C4222418EDB1D7C9F84D051610526085960A1732C7C3D763FFF64EC7F5220998434C896DDA243AE777D0FB213F36B9B19F7E4A244D5C993B8DFED.
id is 1997.
```

**NOTE**: I am taking the output of `statusdata.php` SQL query in JSON format as in the end I am extracting it in android.

Please help me I have tried everything which other similar questions are suggesting but nothing helps

Comment: Seems to me that the query is not finding anything. Have you debugged with turning on mysqli exceptions? Add this to your script to see if anything shows up hinting at errors: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks more like a typo situation. You have this in `login.php`:

```
$_SESSION["key"] = ".$user_key.";
$_SESSION["id"] = ".$user_id.";
```

Which is tainting your original values... by adding needless dots around them. Clean that up by simply assigning as so:

```
$_SESSION["key"] = $user_key;
$_SESSION["id"] = $user_id;
```

And it should begin working better.

---

Side note, you are using `prepare`, but not using `bind_param`. Change your SQL `prepare` to the following (note the `?` placeholders), and add `bind_param`:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT applications.application_id, applications.applicant_name, applications.applicant_aadhaar, applications.applicant_phone, applications.subject, applications.date, applications.description, applications.chairperson_remark, applications.status, officer_accounts.name_of_officer, applications.officer_remark, applications.last_update_on 
         FROM applications INNER JOIN officer_accounts ON applications.account_id = officer_accounts.account_id 
         WHERE applications.application_id = ? AND applications.application_key = ?;");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$user_id,$user_key);
```